# Scala - Get column with condition and groupBy?

Tags: scala

I have the following class:

```
case class worker(
                    age: Int,
                    workclass: String,
                    education: String,
                    educationNum: Int,
                    maritalStatus: String,
                    occupation: String,
                    relationship: String,
                    race: String,
                    sex: String,
                    capitalGain: Int,
                    capitalLoss: Int,
                    hoursPerWeek: Int,
                    nativeCountry: String,
                    income: String
                  )
```

I want to write a function that returns the `workclass` that has the highest number of observations with an `income` > 50000.

I'm new to Scala, so I'm struggling, but I've tried this:

```
 def bestPayWork(c: Seq[worker]): String = {
    var highSalaryGrouped = c.filter(i => i.income > 50000).groupBy(i => i.workclass)
    var result = highSalaryGrouped.max("income", highSalaryGrouped)
    result
  }
```

Comment: You want `maxBy` and no need to use `groupBy` at all; take a look to the **Scaladoc**: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Seq.html#maxBy[B](f:A=%3EB)(implicitcmp:scala.math.Ordering[B]):A - BTW, no need to use `vars` always use `vals` by default, also it would be better to use better names, and `val result = foo; result` can be simplified as just `foo` even more you can write everything as a single expression: `data.filter(w => w.income > 50000).maxBy(w => ???)`

Comment: Thank you! 

I've tried it with `data.filter(w => w.income > 50000).maxBy(w => w.workclass)`, but  it doesn't seem to work, since it returns an `Int`.

What I'm trying to get is the `workclass` as a string, which has the highest number of rows with the given condition (`w => w.income > 50000`).

Comment: Sorry, I just realized there is no `observations` field in the `worker` class,. - What do you mean with `observations`? Number of records?

Comment: Yes, or rows, examples, individuals.

SQL would be:


SELECT count(\*) 
FROM worker 
GROUP BY workclass
WHERE income > 50000
ORDER BY COUNT(\*)
LIMIT 1;

Comment: Ah then yeah a `groupBy` was required, sorry for the confusion. Check micha's answer it works perfectly, I suggested a simplification in the comments. - BTW, if you do not want to deal with the **Option** you can just call `.get` at the end or use `maxBy(_._2.size)._1` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is sample solution assuming that by observations you mean number of workers. I changed returned type to `Option[String]` to cover the case when `c` is empty. Also you need to think what to do with income that's a string and you want to compare it to a number. I just casted it to int, that may not work in your case.

```scala
def bestPayWork(c: Seq[worker]): Option[String] = {
  val highSalaryGrouped = c.filter(i => i.income.toInt > 50000).groupBy(i => i.workclass).map {
    case (workclass, workers) => workclass -> workers.size
  }
  highSalaryGrouped.maxByOption { case (workclass, size) => size }.map(_._1)
}
```

Comment: I would skip the first map and simplify it as `c.filter(w => w.income.toInt > 50000).groupBy(w => w.workclas).maxByOption(_._2.size).map(_._1)`